# Intento agregar datos a una base de datos desde php y me sale un error de bind_param()

Tags: php

Necesito hacer un insert, mi código es el siguiente:

```
    if(validarDatos($egresadosL, $tituladosL, $egresadosP, $tituladosP, $ciclo)){
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'servicio_social');
    $conexion->set_charset('utf8');

    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        $respuesta = ['error' => true];
    } else {

        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO egresotitulacion(EGRESADOSL, TITULADOSL, EGRESADOSP, TITULADOSP, CICLO) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)');
        $statement->bind_param("iiiis", $egresadosL, $tituladosL, $egresadosP, $tituladosP, $ciclo);
        $statement->execute();

        if($conexion->affected_rows <= 0){
            $respuesta = ['error' => true];
        }
        $respuesta = [];
    }
} else {
    $respuesta = ['error' => true];
}
```

Al momento de intentarlo sale un error en bind_param el cual me dice que ha regresado un valor FALSE, revise ya muchas veces y no logro encontrar el error.

El error que me marca es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que tengo entendido bind_param() devuelve un FALSE al haber un error en prepare() o en el mismo bind_param(), después de buscarlo no logro ver en que falla.

Comment: ¿Estás usando `PDO` para establecer la conexión a la base de datos y hacer las consultas?

Comment: Puedes indicarnos la descripción de la tabla egresotitulacion?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y agrega el mensaje de error exacto. También, depura todo lo que estás usando: conexión, variables, preparación de la consulta...

Comment: Para la conexión estoy utilizando mysqli creando un objeto, de la siguiente forma $conexion = new mysql() claro que adentro lleva los parámetros necesarios @DiegoSaravia

Comment: Son 6 columnas, ID mas las 5 que se ven en la consulta (egresadosL, tituladosL, ...). ID no la pido ya que es la llave primaria y se auto incrementa sola al hacer un insert, todos los campos son numéricos menos CICLO que es un varchar de longitud (9) @A.Cedano

Comment: Ya, pero al escribir de forma explícita las columnas como de hecho haces, para el caso que nos ocupa son `5` columnas, no `6` columnas. El fallo no ocurre a causa de eso. Como ya te dije en mi anterior comentario, depura cada objeto y dato que estás usando. Por ejemplo, si para conectar usas `new mysql(...)` como dices, no habrá conexión, porque la clase se llama `mysqli`, por tanto debes usar `new mysqli(...)`

Comment: Te faltan dos validaciones. Puedes adaptar el código, incluyendo esas dos validaciones y cambiando `$msg` por `$respuesta = ['error' => true];` y/o incluyendo un mensaje de error para saber por qué motivo exactamente falla. En el punto en el que lo haces es casi seguro que se debe a un error de sintaxis en la consulta (tabla o columna mal escrita o que no existe en la BD a la que te estás conectado).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que seas *pesimista* cuando programes. Que pienses que lo peor puede ocurrir. Esto te permitirá escribir un código totalmente controlado y robusto, capaz de responder a cualquier crisis. La programación *optimista*, es decir, programar pensando que siempre todo irá bien, es un error, porque no siempre todo va bien.

En el caso concreto de tu pregunta al menos cuatro cosas pueden ocurrir, la primera es que todo vaya bien (ojalá que así sea). Pero hay tres situaciones que entran dentro de la programación *pesimista* que no son cubiertas.

1. ¿Qué pasa si no hay conexión?
2. ¿Qué pasa si la preparación falla (porque la consulta es errónea, porque un nombre de columna cambió, porque esa tabla ya no existe, porque... porque... porque...)
3. ¿Qué pasa si la ejecución falla (aquí hay menos porques, pero un escenario común donde un `INSERT` falla es si viola una restricción de duplicidad o una restricción de llaves foráneas).

Te aseguro que con este código tu programa va a decir lo que le duele. Aquí, si quieres saber exactamente lo que pasa, en etapa de depuración podrás imprimir el mensaje de error interno por ejemplo para tener más detalles.

```
/*
    Se supone que más arriba conectas ^
*/

/*
    1. Asegúrate que hay conexión
*/
if ($conexion) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO egresotitulacion(EGRESADOSL, TITULADOSL, EGRESADOP, TITULADOSP, CICLO) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    /*
        2. Asegúrate que la preparación no falla
    */
    if ($statement = $conexion->prepare($sql)) {
        $statement->bind_param("iiiis", $egresadosL, $tituladosL, $egresadosP, $tituladosP, $ciclo);
        /*
            3. Verifica que no hay errores al ejecutar
        */
        if ($statement->execute()){
            $msg=printf("Filas insertadas: %d", $statement->affected_rows);
        }else{
            $msg="Error ejecutando la consulta";    
        }
    }else{
        $msg="Error preparando la consulta";        
    }
} else {
    $msg="No hay conexión";
}
echo $msg;
```

**PD**: No te alarmes porque las líneas de código se multiplicaron por 3 con respecto a tus tres líneas. Tu código debe ser robusto y responder siempre a cualquier eventualidad. De lo contrario es un programa que en ciertas situaciones no dirá nada, o fallará de forma abrupta y eso sería grave en etapa de producción.

Comment: Creo que ha sido mi culpa por no poner el código completo, editare la pregunta para que se pueda ver completo, esas validaciones que me comentas ya están hechas, pero al no ser la causa del problema pensé que no era importante ponerlas. Supongo que se debe a que es la primera ves hago una pregunta.

Comment: @Juan te faltan todavía **dos validaciones**, y es justo en una de ellas donde está fallando. 1. No estás controlando lo que ocurre con el `prepare` y 2. No estás controlando lo que ocurre con el  `execute` ... En ambas partes el código puede fallar, por los motivos ya explicados o por otros y deberías controlar esos fallos. Si cuando aplicas `bind_param` te dice que el objeto es booleano significa que la preparación falló por error de sintaxis muy probablemente (una columna o tabla mal escrita por ejemplo) y por eso `$statement` es `false` (booleano),

Comment: Muchas gracias, decidí cambiarle el nombre a las columnas de la tabla y copiar dicho nombre al código, también te agradezco la sugerencia de las validaciones, ya que me llevaron a encontrar el error.

Comment: @Juan me alegro de que te haya servido. Siempre es bueno validarlo todo, así tienes siempre control sobre tu código y puedes devolver los mensajes o estatus adecuados para cada situación. Saludos.