# ¿Porqué me da este error intermitentemente? Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, select

Tengo tres consultas SELECT. Funcionan bien la mayoría de las veces, pero 1 de cada 5 veces por ejemplo, salta el siguiente error:

Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in...

La variable conn esta bien, si escribo la consulta select directamente en mysql devuelve resultados, por lo que no veo el fallo. No se porqué está mal, y mucho menos  y es lo que más me intriga por qué ocurre solo algunas veces. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php $sql="SELECT preguntas FROM preguntas WHERE grupo = '$grupopregun' ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conn));
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $pregunta = $mostrar['preguntas'];
  ?>
  <?php }?>
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE preguntas = '$pregunta' ORDER BY RAND()";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $id = $mostrar['id'];
  ?>
  <?php } ?>      
<?php $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas WHERE id= '$id' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
  $respuesta_correcta = $mostrar['respuesta_correcta'];
  $respuesta_incorrecta = $mostrar['respuesta_incorrecta'];
  $respuesta_incorrecta2 = $mostrar['respuesta_incorrecta2'];
  $respuesta_incorrecta3 = $mostrar['respuesta_incorrecta3'];
  ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Intenta haciendo un `echo mysqli_error($conn); die();` antes del while para ver el error que te devuelve

Comment: De por qué sucede algunas veces, no podría responder completamente seguro, pero el error te da porque el `mysqli_query` retorna un resultado de tipo mysqli_result o bool, y si devuelve esto último, no se puede ejecutar el fetch_array. Te recomendaría que prepararas la consulta y la pasaras a mysqli_result primero para asegurarte que obtienes una respuesta de ese tipo

Comment: @gaidyjg no sería una opcion tal vez mas sencilla haciendo el `mysqli_error($conn)` para asi ver directamente el error?

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía también es una buena opción

Comment: Tu problema aquí es la *programación optimista*. He referido eso varias veces en varias respuestas. Cuando escribas un código debes considerar todo aquello que pueda salir mal y afrontarlo, en otras palabras, debes ser lo más pesimista posible. Eso no ocurre aquí. La consulta estaría fallando, pero dado que no controlas eso, no sabes por qué falla el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano siempre te veo hablando de programación optimista, a que te refieres con eso ? respondeme por el chat pls

Comment: @Excorpion lo vengo explicado hace ya tiempo, en varias respuestas y comentarios, por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/341757/29967). Yo llamo *programación optimista* a programar sin ningún control de errores, porque el programador piensa que todo irá bien, cuando a veces algo puede salir mal y debería controlarse en el código. En este mismo código por ejemplo puede darse al menos uno de estos escenarios: 1. No conexión; 2. Error de SQL; 3. Resultados vacíos ... y más cosas. Tres posibles fallos y el programador no controla ninguno de ellos = programación *optimista*.

Comment: @A.Cedano He conseguido solucionarlo. ¿El error? LUn dato que ponía 'Musica' sin tilde. Ha sido eliminarlo y ya. A saber cual seria el error. ¡Esa palabra está maldita! Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda. Empezaré a utilizar la programacion pesimista.

Comment: [Lee esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132804/29967) cuando puedas, creo que podría serte de mucha utilidad en un futuro. Me alegro de que hayas resuleto el problema. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias. Ahora mismo le echo un ojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in

Para mysqli_fetch_array() en el caso de un SELECT se debe entregar un argumento de tipo mysqli_result.
Este resultado es cuando una consulta mysqli ha sido correcta.

En este caso, tu consulta ha fallado.

La forma más simple de saber que resulta mal, es hacer un var_dump() de la consulta en cuestion.

Ejemplo:

```
var_dump($sql); //El string de la consulta
echo "</br>";
var_dump($result); //La respuesta de mysqli_query
```

Comment: ¿el vardump en que lugar lo hago, antes del while, después, antes del mysql_query?

Comment: Justo luego de asignar dicha variable amigo.

Comment: He conseguido solucionarlo. ¿El error? Un dato que ponía 'Musica' sin tilde. Ha sido eliminarlo y ya. A saber cual seria el error. ¡Esa palabra está maldita! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Eso es la codificación amigo. Si usas tildes, debes ser consciente de que codificación estás usando.